# Timout Exception while sending data using Kafka Producer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am getting this error, while producing data to UAT environmet:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for topic-2: 30808 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

In the dev environment it is working fine, data is getting pushed in UAT kafka Logs but it is getting so much time.

```
public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
    config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"ip:port");
    config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
    StringSerializer.class);
    config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
      StringSerializer.class);}
```

Comment: This error can happen for a number of reasons. Please provide the Kafka client logs

Comment: @MickaelMaison I am sending data to topic and this error is coming at producer servers. After increasing memory of UAT servers, in kafka logs i am getting the data sent by producer. but some data is missing.

Comment: below error logs on producer server :  [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] ERROR o.s.k.s.LoggingProducerListener - Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='.(data sending to producer)..' to topic incoming : org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for incoming-0: 30544 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time